# How to check if Collection is not empty using java Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java 8. I am not able to understand what is wrong in the following piece of code. The idea is to sent `Collection<User>` if its not empty. But if the collection is empty than sent `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` Entity response.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/find/pks", 
                method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Collection<User>> getUsers(@RequestBody final Collection<String> pks)
{
    return StreamSupport.stream(userRepository.findAll(pks).spliterator(), false)
         .map(list -> new ResponseEntity<>(list , HttpStatus.OK))
         .orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
}
```

Eclipse shows me error in the following point `.orElse`

> The method `orElse(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND))` is undefined for the type `Stream<ResponseEntity<User>>`

My base interface method looks like following

```
Iterable<T> findAll(Iterable<PK> pks);
```

Comment: Stream.map() returns a Stream, and a Stream doesn't have an orElse() method. You're making your own life complicated by returning an Iterable. Why don't you return a List or a Set, or even a Collection, and use isEmpty()? BTW, what you're mapping is not a list, it's a user. If you really want to keep using Iterable, use iterable.iterator().hasNext() to see if it's empty or not.

Comment: The interface is provided by one of the Spring packages. ))))

Comment: Then use iterable.iterator().hasNext() to see if it's empty or not. But that said, I wouldn't return a 404 in such a case. simply return an 200 with an empty list. 404 is for an unknown resource you try to get. You're searching for resources here, and not finding anything is a valid result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are mixing two things up. The first task is to convert the `Iterable` to a `Collection` which you can indeed solve using the `Stream` API:

```
Collection<User> list=
    StreamSupport.stream(userRepository.findAll(pks).spliterator(), false)
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that this stream is a *stream of `User`s*, not a stream of lists. Therefore you can’t map a `list` to something else with this stream. The `map` operation will map *each element* of the stream to a new element.

Then you can use this list to create the `ResponseEntity`

```
return list.isEmpty()? new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND):
                       new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
```

You can combine these steps by creating a `Collector` performing this steps though this does not provide any advantage, it’s only a matter of style:

```
ResponseEntity<User> responseEntity=
    StreamSupport.stream(userRepository.findAll(pks).spliterator(), false)
   .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
      list -> list.isEmpty()? new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND):
                              new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK) ));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Holger for your answer. I modified your code and included the map function to convert each User into UserDTO.                                         'StreamSupport.stream(userRepository.findAll(pks).spliterator(), false).map(UserDTO::new).collect(
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list -> list.isEmpty() ? new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                        : new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK)));'

Comment: `Collectors.collectingAndThen()` is a nice static method.

Answer (score 5):

It's not necessary, and often a mistake, to cram everything into one line. In this case, you can't - there's no such API for your intention.

Keep it simple:

```
Collection<User> list = <your stream code that gets a list>;
if (list.isEmpty())
    return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
```

but if you absolutely *must*:

```
return <your code>.map(list -> new ResponseEntity<>(list, list.isEmpty() ? HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND : HttpStatus.OK));
```

Comment: He's asking a simplified version of a general problem.

If filtering had been applied to the collection that produced the stream it would not be obvious whether it is empty or not.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your terminal operation of the stream, remember that a stream can only be consumed once.

- Is it a grouping by/statistics operation? Then you'll get a 0 count or an empty map of groups.
- If it collects into a list then it's an empty list.
- If it's one of the methods that returns an `Optional` (such as `findAny`) then you can use the optional's null-checking methods.

Comment: But isn't the concept he's looking for to stream and pass-through, but do some side-logic when something actually passes through ? So not breaking the concept of streaming or consuming once...